# Can i access .jar files in my iphone native application and use them by Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating an iphone application in which some calculations are done for calculating in the .jar file and i want to access them. So is there any way to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. iOS doesn't run JVM code and I don't know of any converters.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not, since there is no Java runtime available on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, .jar is a Java archive, iOS doesn't have a java virtual machine.